# first-child selection does not working

Tags: html, css

WHen I am trying to select img of first article by callig css :first-child property, it is not selecting. I have used **.widget_ci-latest-posts article:first-child** but it is not selecting.

```
<aside class="widget_ci_latest-posts">
<h2>test</h2>
<article class="item">
   <figure class="item-thumb">
       <a><img class="x" src="" /></a>
   </figure>
</article>

<article class="item">
   <figure class="item-thumb">
       <a><img class="x" src="" /></a>
   </figure>
</article>

<article class="item">
   <figure class="item-thumb">
       <a><img class="x" src="" /></a>
   </figure>
</article>
</aside>
```

Comment: because the class widget_ci_latest-posts also has a tag of `h2`

Comment: Have you tried `.widget_ci-latest-posts .item:first-child` ?

Comment: @tR4xX  yes I have tried , but not working.

Comment: Check Nelson's answer there's a typo..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To select first `article` you should use `first-of-type()`  instead of `first-child` because first-child is `h2` element not `article`.

```css
.widget_ci_latest-posts article:first-of-type img  {
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<aside class="widget_ci_latest-posts">
  <h2>test</h2>
  <article class="item">
    <figure class="item-thumb">
      <a><img class="x" src="lorem" /></a>
    </figure>
  </article>

  <article class="item">
    <figure class="item-thumb">
      <a><img class="x" src="lorem" /></a>
    </figure>
  </article>

  <article class="item">
    <figure class="item-thumb">
      <a><img class="x" src="lorem" /></a>
    </figure>
  </article>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 1):

`widget_ci_latest-posts` on your CSS its not `-` should be `_` after `ci`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong class name. Your class is called widget_ci_latest-posts and you're using .widget_ci-latest-posts as a selector. Check the underscores.